# Ubuntu does not boot after install when another hdd/storage is present

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop and Ubuntu does not boot after install.  It requires me to use boot repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair to fix it so it will boot displaying the message 'cannot find root' or similar and loads busybox.  This happens each time I let it boot with a bookable storage device present other than drive Ubuntu is installed on. So each time it boots grub is trashed.

Here is the [output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/11185242/) of boot-repair